# Is there any designer to declare View in ASP.NET MVC in drag and drop way like in WinForms, WPF or Windows Phone applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, designer

I learn ASP .NET MVC using this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

There are few problems and one is creating View in not comfortable way as it would be in desktop WPF, WindForms, Windows Phone applications. Does Visual Studio or Blend or any Microsoft's IDE provides more drag and drop way to declare view in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Sorry to say you that, but you will do a much better job by **not** using the designers. Practice and you'll understand why. I use the WPF designer only as a preview, and edit all my xaml by hand.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I must learn fast and it would help a lot for now. After a while of practice in WPF I also used XAML mostly, but I need a hand now with sth like I described in OP.

Comment: Then you already understand that drag&drop won't learn you anything. I'll write an answer but it won't be what you expect I'm afraid.

Comment: Visual Studio had this in earlier versions of ASP.NET (not MVC), but once you understand HTML and CSS you know that it is very hard to get a decent code using drag and drop tools.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that the drag&drop designers manipulate *components*, and ASP.NET MVC is not component-based. You have a couple *HTML helpers* here and there, but there are no components to manipulate in the first place. Plus, the ASP.NET MVC framework is terse, there are only a very few helpers and templates provided out of the box. It relies heavily on code for things like lists (`@foreach(...)`), whereas ASP.NET WebForms relies on components like `Repeater`, and you pretty much have to write a lot of stuff yourself, which in the end is a good thing because you are not bound by the many limitations of the components ASP.NET WebForms provides.

Perhaps my little explanation can make it more clear why there are no drag&drop editors for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Yoda, maybe you're attempting to learn too many things at once?

**MVC** isn't a technology you will learn overnight I promise you, and looking for drag and drop designers means you're trying to cut corners, and MVC is not a framework you want to do that with as it will come back to bite you.

Instead, I recommend the Pluralsight videos which are available free of charge.

Start with **[MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4)** videos

After you feel competent there, move to the **[MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-aspnet-mvc-5-fundamentals)** videos

The videos on **MVC 5** assume that you already have knowledge on **MVC 4**, so as I said, start with 4.

*(The videos are free of charge thanks to Microsoft footing the bill)*

Answer (score 0):

There is a graphical designer for creating views in drag and drop way, it's a visual studio extension named MVC Visual Designer, you can search it by using Visual Studio menu: TOOL\Extensions and Updates.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Does this still exist?